Google Cloud MySQL 8.x Sluggish
We have two Google MySQL instances. One we designate as Production, the other Test. When they were created 2-3 years ago, they were MySQL 5.x.
Recently, my partner wanted to know if it would be ok to upgrade to 8.x. I said ok but only on Test since I wanted to see if there are any behaviors that were undesirable.
Our apps use API calls to start and stop the instances as-needed; they are not always on (small user base). Typically it takes 3 minutes once the command to start the instance is sent for it to start, verify, and test connection. That is on Production. Test, now that it is upgraded, takes 5-6 or more minutes to accomplish the same steps.
In addition, transactions (read/writes) are sluggish compared to Production (the 5.x instance). What parameters or settings might affect this?
There are features in the newer version that would be useful. If I place a new user on Test just to "get their feet wet", it can be frustrating. Thanks.
